# Finding a formula for the number of functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Let $P_{k}$ denote the set of all subsets of $\{1,2,,\ldots,k\}$. Prove that the number of functions $f$ from $P_{k}$ to $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $f(A\cup B) = \max(f(A), f(B))$ is $1^k +2^k + \ldots n^k$

I have found out the number of subsets of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ but can't seem to proceed further.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every subset of {1,...,k} is a union of singleton sets. Therefore f(A) = max(f({x}) : x in A); that is, f is completely determined by its values on singleton sets.

Conversely, of course, f completely determines its values on singleton sets.

Hence, the number of such $f$ is exactly the number of ways to choose the values of $f$ on singleton sets; that is, $n^k$.

[EDITED to add:] Oops, as both joriki (see his answer) and Henry (see his comment) point out, this is not quite right, because what I should have said is that f is completely determined by its values on *the empty set and* singleton sets.

If $f(\emptyset)=j$ then the $f(\textrm{singleton})$ values have to be $\geq j$, which means that instead of $n^k$ choices for the singleton values we have $(n-j)^k$. Summing this over $0\leq j\leq n$ yields the correct answer: $1+2^k+\cdots+n^k$.

Comment: No, it is not a homework question. Can you please elaborate on your solution?

Comment: Done. (Out of curiosity, where *does* it come from?)

Comment: Sorry, your answer is incorrect. The correct answer is $1^k+2^k+\ldots +n^k$

Comment: Oh yeah, so it is. As joriki points out in his answer, there is the empty set to consider as well, and I forgot about that. joriki's answer has the correct correction; I'll edit mine to include it so there's no danger of it confusing anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

As shown by Gareth in another answer, the number of functions on the non-empty subsets is $n^k$. The condition requires all function values for non-empty subsets to be greater or equal to the function value for the empty set. Thus if $f(\emptyset)=j$ there are $(n-j+1)^k$ options for the function on the non-empty subsets, for a total of

$$\sum_{j=1}^n(n-j+1)^k=\sum_{j=1}^nj^k\;.$$